# High-level programming language for music composition

Tags: programming-languages

I would like to write an interactive song. It would contain state and logic. A listener/user should be able to modify some state vars using a GUI or a MIDI interface. Listener accessible vars don't have to directly represent tempo, pitch or any other music property. They would rather represent values that logic would process in order to make changes to the song.

Do I have to write such platform myself or something fitting my imagination already exists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at [cSounds](http://www.csounds.com/) and [PureData](http://puredata.info/).

Comment: [Max MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/max/) is very simlar to PureData.

Comment: SuperCollider is vastly superior to either (see answer below)

Answer (score 7):

If you are happy to use Java, check out [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/).

Comment: Or else JMusic it has much stronger features compared to JFugue and more flexibility see[1] for applications created by JMusic [1] http://explodingart.com/jmusic/applications.html

Comment: The problem with jfugue is that it needs a super fast processor or else the music will be way way off beat. That's what happened to me. It can't seem to use midi timestamps or anything.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried [PureData](https://puredata.info/), [CSound](http://csound.com/) and [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.github.io/).

CSound is very cumbersome to program in, and has had severe stability issues for my requirements (24bit/96kHz realtime low latency linux) in version 4.

PureData is graphical, which makes it even harder to keep code neat and tidy then with text files. Composing is a pain because you have to build your own composition GUI, which can be powerful, but as long as I'm my only user I find it's just faster to use text.

The winner hands down is SuperCollider, because it is a smalltalk inspired object oriented language which is quite pleasant to work with. It is split into an OSC controlled sound server, and the client language. I can recommend the sound synthesis server and using the language to create instruments without reservation for its excellent stability, great flexibility and incredible power. I've used it live on stage and the performance is incredibly good.

The score creation language suffers from many-hands syndrome; in lack of recent clear leadership there are too many ways to do too many things with too many limitations, but it is still better than CSound because at least you can use reasonable high level structures.

Still looking for a composition language that just gets it right.

Comment: Great answer! How does SuperCollider compare to ChucK? Any experience with that?

Comment: I haven't tried chuck, but from researching it I would guess it is an adequate low-level sound processing option, but not as well suited as a general purpose audio language.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at **[Strasheela](http://strasheela.sourceforge.net/strasheela/doc/index.html)**:

It's a composition system based on the programming language Oz. Learning Oz isn't easy, as it it combines the functional and the logic programming paradigm. However if you liked the **[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)** book, then you will probably like it too.

Strasheela treats music composition as a Constraint Statisfaction Problem (CSP), and seeks "solutions" for it. It means that the music style is defined as mathematical constraints on integer numbers (finite domain), that must be statisfied, and the built-in constraint solving system computes the solutions "automatically".

P.S.: I cannot program in Oz, but I'm on my way of learning it.

Answer (score 2):

See [High level languages for Computer Music](http://www.cs.ucsc.edu/~sasha/proj/musicpaper.pdf) and [Programming Languages used for music](http://www.nosuch.com/plum/cgi/showlist.cgi?sort=name&concise=yes) for help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it covers what you are after for, but have a look at [Java Sound API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/). For a FAQ about what it can do see [here](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_midi.html). The benefits are that is already bundled in the SDK and JRE and that is cross platform. Also, you could build the GUI using any Java toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't for the interactive bits, I'd suggest looking at [Haskore](http://www.haskell.org/haskore/) or [Nyquist](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/music/web/music.software.html), both effectively being DSLs for music generation.

Definitely take a look at [Alex McLean's livecoding](http://yaxu.org/category/livecoding/) demos, though.  It's more flexible and interactive as you can possibly imagine, using [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net//) through [OpenSoundControl](http://opensoundcontrol.org/).

Comment: DSL = Domain-specific language

Answer (score 1):

Answer is for .NET:
I found something, checkout [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) by [Mark Heath](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/search/label/NAudio), a great .NET music library I would say it should be contained in the BCL.

[midi-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/) is another great C# project by Tom Lokovic.

Answer (score 1):

For music interaction, PureData, Max/MSP and OpenMusic (these two last are from IRCAM) are the best. PureData is freeware.  Google them!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to do, but here is a list of some CL music software, both for composition and cognition: http://www.cliki.net/Music

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an [Audio Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_programming_language).  Another option you should consider is [Processing](http://processing.org/) - used by many artists and musicians for this type of work.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Its a shame that none said about Chuck................
Chuck is a programming language that is specifically built for music/audio generation and composition.
You can download Chuck at http://chuck.stanford.edu
its a lot easier to use,and is a lot familiar to c,c++,java etc,however its easier to  learn too.You can find at Coursera about chuck for free from California arts university,link [here.](https://class.coursera.org/chuck101-001/class)