# How to "slow down" a MIDI file (ideally in Python)?

Tags: python, midi

I have background music for some songs available in both .MID and .KAR formats, but in each case it's being played somewhat faster than I'd like. What's the simplest way to create either .MID or .KAR files with the same content but at a slower tempo -- say, one slowed down by 20% or so, another by 15%, a third by 25%, and so on?

Ideally, I'd prefer a cross-platform Python script (since that would allow me to easily experimentally tweak the source to converge to the exact effect I want;-), but I'll take any free solution that runs in Linux (Ubuntu 8.04 if it matters) and Mac (Mac OS X 10.5, but 10.6 compatibility preferred).

Comment: Have you taken a look at the OSC format? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could edit the file, as per http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html

Although there probably is a MIDI reading/writing library already. In fact, it was a matter of seeing the related questions: [Simple, Cross Platform MIDI Library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569321/simple-cross-platform-midi-library-for-python)

> Set Tempo
>
> This meta event sets the
> sequence tempo in terms of
> microseconds per quarter-note which is
> encoded in three bytes. It usually is
> found in the first track chunk,
> time-aligned to occur at the same time
> as a MIDI clock message to promote
> more accurate synchronization. If no
> set tempo event is present, 120 beats
> per minute is assumed. The following
> formula's can be used to translate the
> tempo from microseconds per
> quarter-note to beats per minute and
> back.

```
MICROSECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60000000

BPM = MICROSECONDS_PER_MINUTE / MPQN
MPQN = MICROSECONDS_PER_MINUTE / BPM
```

```
Meta Event  Type    Length  Microseconds/Quarter-Note
255 (0xFF)  81 (0x51)   3   0-8355711
```

Comment: Ah well, doesn't look like I'm going to get any more direct technique, so thanks for this one, @Vinko.

Comment: So much for SO being excellent, huh? :-) When you **REALLY** need it, it always fails.

Answer (score 15):

As Vinko says, you can edit the midifile, but since it's a binary format, squeezed into the least number of bits possible, it helps to have help.

This is a midi-to-text converter (and vice-versa):
http://midicomp.opensrc.org/
I've been using it quite a bit lately.  it's pretty trivial to do text processing (e.g. searching for line with "Tempo") for simple operations once you have the midifile as text.  haven't tried on mac (compiled with no problem on ubuntu 8.04).

Regarding midifile tempo specifically, it's really easy to slow down or speed up playback since the timing of events is specified in terms of "ticks", whose real duration in seconds is determined by the tempo parameter described in Vinko's quote.  I believe time signature is not so relevant, and is mainly for displaying bars/beats correctly when opened in a midi sequencer.

Also, aside from pyPortMidi, there are a couple of other python midi modules around.

[hmmm... it seems i can only post on link per post, being a new user. i'll try posting the links to the python modules in a couple comments or another couple answers...]

Comment: Python module for reading, writing, creating/editing etc midi files:  
<http://www.mxm.dk/products/public/pythonmidi>

Comment: Class for reading and writing midi files (this posting seems to be the only source):  
<http://groups.google.com/group/alt.sources/msg/0c5fc523e050c35e>

Comment: I also found this, though i haven't tried it:  
<http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/65fa6c4bb74bca17>

Answer (score 5):

You can use [music21](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/index.html) to do this, though I have only tested it on OSX 10.10.1.

```
import music21

fctr = 1.25 # scale (in this case stretch) the overall tempo by this factor
score = music21.converter.parse('song.mid')
newscore = score.scaleOffsets(fctr).scaleDurations(fctr)

newscore.write('midi','song_slow.mid')
```

Offsets are like the timestamps of each note, and durations is how long the note is sounded, I believe applying the same scale factor to each is kind of like adjusting the tempo.

If you are like me then you are listening to the same songs 7 years later and can give this a try! Otherwise, I hope this helps someone else who woke up today like me and was scratching my head trying to solve this problem easily.

Comment: fastScore = score.augmentOrDiminish(1.25) -- will scale the durations and the offsets and some other things to make the score output properly as well.

Answer (score 1):

tested the version by @dermen on Windows, Python 3.8. Had to tweak it a bit, but still works!

```
import music21

fctr = 1.5 # scale (in this case stretch) the overall tempo by this factor
score = music21.converter.Converter()
score.parseFile('home.mid')
newscore = score.stream.augmentOrDiminish(fctr)
newscore.write('midi','song_slow.mid')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar interest as your post.  I just came across this library which looks very promising:

http://web.mit.edu/music21/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Replacing the tempo.MetronomeMark object at the beginning of each staff with a new one should do the trick.  Note that currently music21 will quantize any MIDI file. Just got added to our todo list to make that optional.