# reading midi input

Tags: python, input, midi

is there a module to read midi input (live) with python?

Comment: What's you re requirements? Platforms? Platform independent? Sysex, etcs? All these things are important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569321/simple-cross-platform-midi-library-for-python, although that other question doesn't make sense (MIDI sounds?) and is less specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [PyPortMidi](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~harrison/code.html) successfully in 2006 to record Midi input in real time (on OS X).  It should work on Windows, OS X, and Linux.  It was very light on the processor side, which was great!

Comment: @terabytest An example file is provided, I believe.

Comment: There is a version of PyPortMidi included in PyGame that has some updates applied.

Answer (score 1):

I had this discussion like ages ago once, and the consensus kinda ended up on using [MidiShare](http://midishare.sourceforge.net/), which has Python bindings. But things may have moved on since then, that was like 2004 or something. So it's not a recommendation, just a "check it out".