# Getting input from MIDI devices live (Python)

Tags: python, midi

I've got a trigger finger (MIDI tablet) and I want to be able to read its input live and make python execute actions depending on the pressed key.

I need it for Windows, and preferably working with python 2.5 +

Thanks

Comment: You can edit your old question instead of posting the same question again.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554362/reading-midi-input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/) includes a built-in [midi module](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html), available for Linux, Windows and MacOS and is very well supported.

For example, here is the documentation for [pygame.midi.Input](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Input):

```
  Input is used to get midi input from midi devices.
  Input(device_id)
  Input(device_id, buffer_size)
        Input.close - closes a midi stream, flushing any pending buffers.   closes a midi stream, flushing any pending buffers.
        Input.poll - returns true if there's data, or false if not. returns true if there's data, or false if not.
        Input.read - reads num_events midi events from the buffer.  reads num_events midi events from the buffer.
```

If you're looking for an alternative, have a look at [PythonInMusic](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) in the Python wiki.

There are various different projects related to MIDI input and output there, some for Windows as well. (Click the little > sign after each project to follow the link to the project homepage)

I have not used any of them personally, but I'm sure it will help you get started.

Comment: how do i get to know the device id?

Comment: Have a look at the other functions on that page. There is one to return the default input device: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.get_default_input_id

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use PyGame, you will have to process the events by **polling**, so it won't be as real-time as you would want to. Ideally, there should be a libary to **hook** functions to the midi events.