# Midi usb controlling /script code

Tags: controls, midi

So I have a MIDI controller TraktorF1 that runs on Windows 10 and uses 16 pads from which I read out the MIDI data input/output with midi ox. so I want to learn how I could write / script or code that will allow me to press one of these pads and allow the device to open for example : a directory on my computer like This PC > Downloads . 
It seems to me this is the best basic thing I can learn , later on I will try to make it more interesting and functional like : controlling some simple programmed games and so on.

Any guidance for any programming language would be awesome.
Help me out friends ! This is something that interest me a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting input from MIDI devices live (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554896/getting-input-from-midi-devices-live-python)

Comment: MIDI input and output had already been read with midi ox. Can you explain me how can that documentation for pygame.midi.Input: work on my question ?