# Live audio processing and playback

Tags: python, numpy, audio, audio-streaming

Is it possible to access real-time audio with python and then play it real-time.

So here's what i've been tryna do:

I am basically looking to make a program which accesses input data in midi format from a digital instrument and then play it on the local device but slightly edited all in real-time
I see the option of taking an audio file as an input then storing it as wav and playing it but this doesn't make it anywhere close to a live audio processing.

I've come across many ways to input real time audio data and process it but i've seen none for real time playback

Any recommendations on libraries or anything would be of great help

Comment: This sounds less like real-time audio input and more like real-time midi input. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554896/getting-input-from-midi-devices-live-python

Comment: Pygame will allow you to pass audio buffers to output as well. This is really 4-5 questions wrapped depending on how you slice it. I’d recommend decomposing your problem first.