# Python interface for outputting MIDI files or text that's readable by audio programs

Tags: python, audio, midi

I am looking for a python package or library that will allow me to programmatically output a file format (e.g. MIDI) that can be read by audio/sound processing programs, like LogicPro or iDrum.  What are the best options for this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569321/simple-cross-platform-midi-library-for-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large number of possibilities are listed [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic), especially under the "Midi Mania" header. For your requirements, and the various packages' descriptions, it seems to me that [pythonmidi](http://www.mxm.dk/products/public/pythonmidi) might suit you best, but I have no first-hand experience with it.