# Using Python to Create MIDI's

Tags: python

Essentially, I'm trying to create MIDI's from scratch and put them online. I'm open to different languages, but prefer to use Python (one of the 2's, if that makes any difference.) and was wondering what library I should use. Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate of [Simple, Cross Platform MIDI Library for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569321/simple-cross-platform-midi-library-for-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this is what you are looking for:

[Simple, Cross Platform MIDI Library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569321/simple-cross-platform-midi-library-for-python)

[MidiUtil](http://code.google.com/p/midiutil/) can create MIDI files in python.

Comment: Can it do multiple instruments? Sorry, I'm a complete noob to sound/music programming.

Comment: Literally the first paragraph of the website I posted, "MIDIUtil is a pure Python library that allows one to write muti-track Musical Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI) files from within Python programs. It is object-oriented and allows one to create and write these files with a minimum of fuss." :PP

Answer (score 0):

```
from midiutil import MIDIFile

def create_midi(chord_progression, file_name='jazz_piano_progression.mid', tempo=120):
    # Create a MIDI file
    midi = MIDIFile(1)
    midi.addTempo(0, 0, tempo)

    # Define the chords and their durations
    chords = [
        {'pitch': [60, 63, 67, 70], 'duration': 4},  # Cm7
        {'pitch': [65, 68, 72, 75], 'duration': 4},  # Fm7
        {'pitch': [70, 74, 77, 81], 'duration': 4},  # Bb7
        {'pitch': [64, 68, 71, 75], 'duration': 4}   # Ebmaj7
    ]

    time = 0
    for chord in chords:
        for pitch in chord['pitch']:
            midi.addNote(0, 0, pitch, time, chord['duration'], 100)
        time += chord['duration']

    # Save the MIDI file
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as midi_file:
        midi.writeFile(midi_file)

# Generate MIDI file with the specified chord progression
create_midi([{'Cm7': ['C', 'E♭', 'G', 'B♭']},
             {'Fm7': ['F', 'A♭', 'C', 'E♭']},
             {'Bb7': ['B♭', 'D', 'F', 'A♭']},
             {'Ebmaj7': ['E♭', 'G', 'B♭', 'D']}
             ], 'jazz_piano_progression.mid', tempo=120)
```

Answer (score -2):

Perl has the module MIDI::Simple. I remember an article about it in the now extinct The Perl Journal:

http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol4_1/tpj0401-0018.html

Comment: They asked for a solution in Python.