# Midi library for Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, midi, coremidi, opensoundcontrol

I'm looking for a python midi library (preferably python3) which will allow me to produce midi commands so that I can control midi instruments on my mac.

I'm also interested in open sound control capabilities but this is less important.

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PyGame](http://pygame.org) is a good starting point.

Comment: Is it possible to send Control Messages such a Pitch Bending with PyGame?

Comment: Yes, it supports all MIDI message types, including CC.

Comment: PyGame on the mac does not support writing midi to a port.

Comment: While pygame *is* a good starting point, this is a very short answer.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the python wrapper of PortMidi, [pyPortMidi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPortMidi/0.0.3), which is where the MIDI support in PyGame comes from.

A good resource is the [PythonInMusic](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) page on the Python wiki.

Comment: Version 0.0.3 - released March 15, 2005. Might be waiting a while for Python 3 support :)

Comment: pygame includes pyportmidi 0.0.6: (Feb 25, 2011)

Answer (score 0):

Could be a repeat of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276139/using-python-to-create-midis/7276218#7276218). If not, there is definitely good Python MIDI info in that post.

So, basically you might want to use [MidiUtil](http://code.google.com/p/midiutil/), a Python module.

Comment: This util allows one to create midi files, not midi data that can be sent to instruments.